# Unable to enter the integer value in textbox using SendKeys("1") in Jmeter webdriver Sampler 4.6.0

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

In jmeter selenium webdriver sampler 4.6.0, using the sendKeys("1") or Javascript, unable to enter the integer value in textbox using java or groovy. could you please check the screenshot

[image]

Jmeter 5.4.3 or 5.5
Selenium Webdriver Sampler 4.6.0 or 4.7.0
Java language

Answer (score 0):

Just switch to `groovy`

[image]

When you choose `java` from the "Language" dropdown it is not real "java", it's [Beanshell interpreter](https://beanshell.github.io/) which is not 100% Java compatible and doesn't support Java features like [Generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) and this is the cause of the error you're getting.

Moreover [it's recommended to use Groovy for any form of scripting since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting). See [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) article for more information.